# "If" nested inside a "for" only enters once

Tags: python

Having problems with an IF inside a for.

```
print (frames_min)
print (frames_max)

for f in range(frames_min, frames_max):
    if ((f >= 96) and (f < 144)):
        f += 3
    print("A",f)
```

Result:

[image: Output]

Why not 100, 103, 106, 109 ??

Comment: because of the way `for` loops work in python, every time it iterates, f is reassigned as the next entry in your iterable

Comment: `f` is reset at the start of every iteration of the loop. That is what `for f in range(...)` does. If you want to conditionally increase the variable, you might use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: as @khelwood said, you can use a while loop, or you can use `iter()` and `next(iter)` logic

Comment: Both the loop and the if statement are changing the value of `f` on every iteration, not just the if statement. Print the value before and after the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python `for` iterates through each variable, rather than by indices:

```
print (frames_min)
print (frames_max)

for f in range(frames_min, frames_max):
    if ((f >= 96) and (f < 144)):
        f += 3
    print("A",f)
```

Here you are increasing the value of `f` by 3, but `f` represents the actual number being stored there rather than an index. If this isn't desired you can use `while`

```
print (frames_min)
print (frames_max)
i = frames_min
while i < frames_max:
    print(i)
    i += 3
```

Alternatively you can use the ['step' parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) of the range command to make it give every 3rd number:

```
print (frames_min)
print (frames_max)

for f in range(frames_min, frames_max, 3):
    print("A",f)
```

Will do what I think is your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use while loop, instead of for loop.

```
 frames_min=97
 frames_max=144

 print (frames_min)
 print (frames_max)

 f=97
 while f >=frames_min and f<= frames_max:
    f = f + 3
 print("A",f)
```